# Generating Alarm with notification issue in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Here is my code.
From where i am not able to generate alarm programmatically..

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int id = (int) cal.getTimeInMillis();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,MyScheduledReceiver.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("taskTitle", taskTitle.getText().toString());
    myIntent.putExtra("taskDetails", taskDetails.getText().toString());

     cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
     cal.set(year, mon, day,tp.getCurrentHour(),tp.getCurrentMinute());
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id,
            myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

I declared in the manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".MyScheduledReceiver"></receiver>
```

An in the broadcast reciever.

```
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationManager manger = (NotificationManager)     
context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Combi Note",
 System.currentTimeMillis());
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 
NOTIFICATION_ID, 
new Intent(context, MyScheduledReceiver.class), 0);
        Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
        String title=extras.getString("taskTitle");
    String note=extras.getString("taskDetails");
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, note, title, contentIntent);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    manger.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, notification);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused - you mentioned that you are unable to generate the alarm, which I take to mean that onReceive(...) of your Receiever is never invoked?  Is this the case?

Comment: Ok leave it if i want to genrate notification than wether it is the right way... it is a kind of reminders.. i think u got my point. Notification of any task for example task on 17 march 2012 at 7:00 pm

Comment: I see no obvious errors in your Alarm code so most likely its something else like the alarm time you are setting is not what you expect or your Receiver is not doing what you expect etc.  For the sake of simplicity I would just display a toast message inside of your Receiver's onReceive(...).  I would also comment out your cal.set(...) call and change your cal.setTimeInMillis to cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000); so that when you run your app, if you don't see a Toast msg, you know it's not firing.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar and it works.

First hi declare a Pending:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Global.a, EventAlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", ""+cd.title);
    intent.putExtra("desc", ""+cd.description);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            Global.a.getApplicationContext(), (int) (cd.alarmTime), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Global.a.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cd.alarmTime, pendingIntent);
```

and in EventAlarmReceiver class i have:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String text = String.valueOf(intent1.getCharSequenceExtra("title"));

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.id.icon,
            text, System.getTimeInMillis());

    notification.vibrate = new long[]{100,250,300,330,390,420,500};

    // Hide the notification after its selected     
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowEventActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", String.valueOf(intent1.getCharSequenceExtra("title")));
    intent.putExtra("desc", String.valueOf(intent1.getCharSequenceExtra("desc")));


    String text1 = String.valueOf(intent1.getCharSequenceExtra("desc"));

    PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.getTimeInMillis() , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, text, text1, activity);

    notificationManager.notify((int)System.getTimeInMillis(), notification);
```

make sure that in the Manifest you declare declare the package where the Receiver is: for example in my case the EventAlarmReceiver class is the package com.app.name.notifications so in the manifest i have:

```
<receiver android:name=".notifications.EventAlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```